# Spring Cloud Data Flow Add TimeStamp to File Name

Tags: spring-boot, file, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, sink

I am trying to use the out of the box file Source and Sink stream applications with Spring Cloud data flow. I am trying to move a file from one folder to another. When the file arrives at the sink I would like to rename it and append a date or timestamp to the file name. How do I do this? I assume the name-expression field but I am not sure what values this can take. Anything I try in this field seems to cause an error.

I would like the file to be something like test20191122.txt

[image: file sink props]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
'test' + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(new java.util.Date()) + '.txt'
```

...should work.

Comment: I tried this in both the name field and the name expression field. It seems to reject the parenthesis and the the plus signs.

Comment: It should work in the expression field; try putting `"..."` around the whole thing.

Comment: does it need to use single quotes as well? Is this field actually taking javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the UI, just the SpringExpressionLanguage for the expression; SpEL requires single or double quotes around literals. I asked on an internal chat what kind of "magic" is required to configure a SpEL expression like that. Waiting for a reply.

Comment: That did the trick. Your string expression was perfect, it just needed the double quotes around it and I placed it in the name expression field. I left the name field blank. The output file was named test20191125.txt - Thank you!

Comment: Great. Glad to help.